# Why is my PHP not recognizing my other classes when called from AJAX?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have created a database with some product classes. I have tested the classes directly in the HTML and they work. I can call products and populate my website store directly from instantiating a PHP class. I want to call this function from ajax so that I can increase the number of products without reloading the page but when I call the ajax function it says the parent class is not recognized. So I call the productsview class method PopulateStoreProducts but it throws and error saying that it cant find the class products eventhough its been extended and if I call the class it works. Not sure if I have to use JSON encode given that it works just by running it. Here is the code:

Products View Class (Works When called independently)

```
    <?php

class ProductsView extends Products{
public function populateStoreProducts(){
        
        $storeproducts = $this->getAllProducts();
        
        $numberOfProducts = count($storeproducts);
        
        $id = array_column($storeproducts, 'ID');
        $name = array_column($storeproducts, 'Name');
        $description = array_column($storeproducts, 'Description');
        $price = array_column($storeproducts, 'Price');
        $image = array_column($storeproducts, 'Image_Link');
        // echo print_r($first_names[1]);
        
        $i = 1;
        $j = 0;
        
        $output = [];
        
        
        while($i<$numberOfProducts){        
            $i++;
            $j++;
            
            $output[$j] = 
             '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">'.
             '<div id="'.$id[$j]. 
             '" class="card h-100">'.
             '<img class="card-img-top" src="'.$image[$j].'" alt="">'.
             '<div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">'.$name[$j].'</h2>'.
             '</hr>'.
             '<h4>Price '.$price[$j].'</h4>'.
             '</div></div></div>';


             echo $output[$j];
}
}
```

PHP File to instantiate the class (Works when called independently)

```
<?php

    include_once 'productsview.class.php';
    
            $testProduct = new ProductsView();
            $testProduct->populateStoreProducts();
        
        
?>
```

And finally the js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#products").load("classes/populatestore.php");

});
```

My script link is at the end of the body and my jquery link is inside the head. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Products" not found.

Comment: In case it is useful to anyone I solved it by using the require_once in all classes. Not sure if its the best approach tho. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Good practice would be to `require_once` any class used within another class, including the one it extends, all interfaces it implements. You do not need to require every file in every other file, just the ones each file depends on. As your projects get larger and you gain experience, start using the [Composer class autoloader](https://getcomposer.org)

Comment: `include_once` is not throwing any errors, that is why you don't see anything. Good practice is to use `require_once` everywhere or use `composer + psr4`